# Switch Spaces via Mouse

Tags: display, desktop

I am using two Spaces on my mojave and I can use `Ctrl + Left/Arrow` to change the screen.

But isn't there a way to use only mouse to change the space instead of using keyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a Magic Mouse, then **yes**!
Head over to System Preferences > Mouse. You will find an option there to set it to a two finger swipe to the left/right.

For other mice, **ususally no**. Some mice, like Logitech Master support all kinds of stuff though with the Logitech Options.
A workaround would be to set a Hot Corner (System Preferences > Mission Control > Hot Corners), then you don't need your keyboard, but it'll take longer.

Comment: Mine is logitech

Comment: What exact model is it? Maybe head over to Logitechs website to check if it is being supported by the Logitech Options software. But if its older than, let's say 10 years, I am pretty sure it won't be supported.

Comment: M100r, old one..

Comment: How can I check if it is supported or not?

Comment: My quick google search unfortunately didn't get me any useful results. You can always just download the software and Logitech Options (LO) should tell you if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

I have an iMac with the Logitech G305 Gaming Mouse... I have just configured it to perform the Ctrl + Left/Arrow & Ctrl + Right/Arrow.

1. Set G3 / scroll wheel press button to: Ctrl
2. Set G4 / Bottom side hot key to: Left
3. Set G5 /  Top side hot key to: Right

To get the same swipe between apps as the Magic Mouse... press & hold down Ctrl (scroll wheel down) first, & then press either left or right. This performs the same action...

Hope this helps someone...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I read in the comments that you are using Logitech, so with Logitech Options installed ([install link here](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/options)), you can set mouse gestures to switch Spaces left or right.  You can also set the secondary scroll wheel of the MX Master 2S to do that.

I recommend you also activate smooth scrolling, if possible.

Comment: I think I have to buy a better logitech mouse.